# How would I use _.mapKey over this array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following array of objects. I would like to change the key "text" to be named label

```
[
  {id: 0, text: "blue"},

  {id: 1, text: "green"},

  {id: 2, text: "orange"},

  {id: 3, text: "yellow"}
]
```

The "id" has to stay as is.

I can use lodash or javascript.

Comment: have you used mapKey? or map?

Comment: Hi @Isaac, I tried doing a forEach and inside it _.mapKey but I get an undefined response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.map()` method to rename key in array of objects.

```js
var data = [
  {id: 0, text: "blue"},

  {id: 1, text: "green"},

  {id: 2, text: "orange"},

  {id: 3, text: "yellow"}
]

data = data.map(el => {
  return {
    id: el.id,
    label: el.text
  }
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do using .map

```js
let arr=[
  {id: 0, text: "blue"},

  {id: 1, text: "green"},

  {id: 2, text: "orange"},

  {id: 3, text: "yellow"}
];

let arr1=[];
arr1=arr.map(a=>({id:a.id,label:a.text}));
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `forEach` and an array with the targets

This alternative will mutate the original array.

```js
let array = [{id: 0, text: "blue"},{id: 1, text: "green"}, {id: 2, text: "orange"},  {id: 3, text: "yellow"}],
    target = [['text', 'label'], ['ele', 'stack']];

array.forEach(o => {      
  target.forEach(([src, dest]) => {
    if (o[src]) {
      Object.assign(o, {[dest]: o[src]});
      delete o[src];
    }
  });
});
    
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```